# Execute php script with crontab doesn't work

Tags: php, server, cron

I'm trying to execute a php script every day to send an automatic email to the clients that have contacted me. To try if it works I'm trying to execute it every minute. I have followed these steps:

1. `whereis php` prompts

```
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/share/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
```

2. Then I make `crontab -e` and add a line:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www2/www/centros-sbc.com/public_html/mail/mail_automatico.php &>> /dev/null
```

Then I wait a minute and nothing happens. Have any idea?

Comment: Prior to edit, this showed a crontab of "1 * * * *" just for the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I succeed by making it more simple:

> - - - - - /usr/bin/php /var/www2/www/centros-sbc.com/public_html/mail/mail_automatico.php

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Every minute is "* * * * *"

You've done "every hour at one minute past"

Comment: Then maybe the path to the script is wrong. How have you checked it? What output do you expect?

Comment: I expect the email to be sent, the path is ok as I have checked it with 'cd path'

Comment: Have you checked the command by running it, eg: php /var/www2/www/centros-sbc.com/public_html/mail/mail_automatico.php. Does it work?

Comment: Yes, it works, but I have had to try two times because with copy-paste it didn't worked (because of the invisible \r char)

Comment: Are you saying you have a carriage return (\r) in your crontab file? If so, get it all on one line.

Comment: no, I just copied the path from here to execute php path, but in the crontab I wrote it myself to avoid that so it wouldn't be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried 
/usr/bin/php **-f** /var/www2/www/centros-sbc.com/public_html/mail/mail_automatico.php &>> /dev/null

-f option is here to execute the file (your file) mail_automatico.php

Answer (score 0):

1) check if your cron job is working (service crond status | systemctl status crond)

2) `&>/dev/null` is normally equal to `> /dev/null 2>&1`.
But some shells doesn't support it.

have you tried `> /dev/null 2>&1` instead `&>/dev/null` ?